# How to configure apcu for doctrine in Symfony5

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony5

In Symfony4 I was using the following configuration for doctrine apcu caching:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
```

After upgrading to Symfony5 I am getting an error:

> Unknown cache of type "apc" configured for cache "metadata_cache" in entity 
>      manager "default".

When changing the it to the following configuration it works:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
```

But what kind of cache am I using now? And how can I switch it to apcu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem in Symfony 4.4.5

You should first install the [Symfony Cache Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#installation). Then, you should configure cache pools, services and doctrine cache as follows:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.result_cache_provider

services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
```

The above configration is taken from [here](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/1.6/config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml).