# Symfony - Doctrine cache configuration error

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine

I try to define cache for queries & results with Doctrine in a Symfony 5.4 project but I have an error message when my application is in production environment (this error is not present in development environnement).

Message:

```
Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.result_cache_pool", path: "doctrine.result_cache_pool -> doctrine.system_cache_pool.compatibility_layer -> doctrine.system_cache_pool -> doctrine.result_cache_pool.compatibility_layer -> doctrine.result_cache_pool".
```

doctrine.yaml file in config/packages/prod directory:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

services:
    doctrine.system_cache_pool:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\Psr6\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.orm.default_result_cache'
    doctrine.result_cache_pool:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\Psr6\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.orm.default_metadata_cache'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

I have read the official documentation from Symfony but the part about "services" section is missing.

Comment: The following answer inject some other services: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60875064/2257664

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your cache in prod ? or delete the prod folder which is in var/cache